# How to switch workspaces without using a keyboard in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Each operation should be doable both with mouse and keyboard.

How to switch workspaces without a keyboard in Xfce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to switch workspaces with mouse wheel.

Move your mouse to hover the *Workspace Switcher* on Xfce panel and then rotate mouse wheel up or down.

[image: Xfce Workspace Switcher]

This behavior is enabled by default (see settings):

[image: Xfce Workspace Switcher - mouse wheel]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the "Workspace Switcher" item added to your panel.  Then just click with the mouse on which panel you want.

Comment: You should add more information about that item you just mention, for instance the link to the wiki within the repository, and some visual instructions would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control than what the built-in keyboard shortcuts give (e.g. switching workspaces from a script), you can switch workspaces with [wmctrl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl).

`wmctrl -d` will list workspaces ("desktops"), while e.g. `wmctrl -s 0` will switch to the first one.